# Results are empty with $wpdb->prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, wordpress

I am working in WordPress and my $wpdb select query works without prepare but when I use the proper escaping and use $wpdb->prepare ... with prepare results never show up and results show when I don't use %s and prepare ... what is there that I am missing ... thanks and no error show up in inspect screen with prepare and results also don't show. Please guide what approach to use to save from sql injection then.

This work

```
$sql = "SELECT 1user.uid, 1user.username, 1user.competition, 1user.path, 1user.category, Sum(votes.votes) AS votessum, describebaby, current FROM 1user LEFT JOIN votes on 1user.uid=votes.uid GROUP BY 1user.uid, 1user.username, 1user.competition, 1user.path, 1user.category HAVING 1user.category = '$category' && 1user.competition = '$comp' ORDER BY 1user.uid DESC";
```

This does not work

```
$sql = "SELECT 1user.uid, 1user.username, 1user.competition, 1user.path, 1user.category, Sum(votes.votes) AS votessum, describebaby, current FROM 1user LEFT JOIN votes on 1user.uid=votes.uid GROUP BY 1user.uid, 1user.username, 1user.competition, 1user.path, 1user.category HAVING 1user.category = %s && 1user.competition = %s ORDER BY 1user.uid DESC";


$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql),$category,$comp) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you added the parentheses in the wrong place, it needs to be after your variables.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql,$category,$comp)) or die($wpdb->print_error());
```

Comment: ok @Augwa ... thanks ... wait let me try this and just please also tell that should I use prepare with insert and update queries also just like this or for them some protection already exist ... thanks

Comment: you should **ALWAYS** use prepared statements when accepting user data. Even when the data source is trusted it's still good practice to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: so for update and insert statements I also use this ... thanks please tell

Comment: How are we mixing `mysql_error` with prepared statements here? `mysql_*` api does not support them so that `mysql_error()` call is useless

Comment: @Zlogic yes you can use prepared statements for all types of SQL queries ... SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

Comment: Also as per @Hanky웃Panky comment he is correct. I wasn't even looking at that when I did this, I've updated my response to what it should be for wordpress.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky judging by the lack of `?` or `:named` placeholders, I'd say this is Wordpress' hacked-on prepared statement